# How to identify a jar file for particular package

Tags: java, swing, jar, package

I wrote a simple editor using swing components and JAPI.When I run the program it shows some errors.I add the JAPI jar file (japi-lib-swing-action-0.3.0.jar) to the my project Libraries folder.I am using NetBeans IDE.It shows the following error "the import net.sf.japi.swing.ActionMethod cannot be resolved ". Which jar file contains that package.

Here is sample code:

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import net.sf.japi.swing.ActionFactory;
import static net.sf.japi.swing.ActionFactory.getFactory;
import net.sf.japi.swing.ActionMethod;
import net.sf.japi.swing.ActionProvider;

public class Editor implements ActionProvider {
/** Action Factory. */
private static final ActionFactory ACTION_FACTORY =  getFactory("net.sf.japi.examples.editor");

/** The supported editor action names and their corresponding kit action names. */
private static final Map<String, String> editorActionNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    editorActionNames.put("editCut",       DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
    editorActionNames.put("editCopy",      DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
};

/** Application frame. */
private final JFrame frame = new JFrame(ACTION_FACTORY.getString("frame.title"));

/** Editor component. */
private final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

/** FileChooser for opening and saving files. */
private final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

/** Currently opened file.
 * Maybe <code>null</code> in case the current document was not already saved.
 */
private File file;

/** Create the Editor. */
public Editor() {
    ACTION_FACTORY.addActionProvider(this);
    frame.setJMenuBar(ACTION_FACTORY.createMenuBar(true, "editor", this));
    frame.add(ACTION_FACTORY.createToolBar(this, "editor"), NORTH);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(textPane));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Nullable public Action getAction(final String key) {
    for (final Action action : textPane.getActions()) {
        final String realKey = editorActionNames.get(key);
        if (realKey != null && realKey.equals(action.getValue(Action.NAME))) {
            ACTION_FACTORY.initAction(true, action, key);
            return action;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/** Action method.
 * @used
 */
@ActionMethod public void fileNew() {
    textPane.setText("");
    file = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the relevant jar to your classpath/build path in Netbeans. Check your project settings.

I can confirm that ActionMethod does exist in `japi-lib-swing-action-0.3.0.jar`:

```
 $ jar tf ~/../Downloads/japi-lib-swing-action-0.3.0.jar | grep ActionMethod
net/sf/japi/swing/action/ActionMethod.class
```

I'm reviewing your question again and you say

> "the import net.sf.japi.swing.ActionMethod cannot be resolved "

I think you have the package name wrong, it should be "net.sf.japi.swing.action" - you are missing the last "action".

You can use a standard zip-file extraction program, such as winzip, or 7-zip to inspect the contents of your jar-files.

In my experience Java is pretty poor at identifying which jars contain which classes (or even packages). I use a shell function like this, it pretty much does the job:

```
function findJar {

  basedir=$1
  searchString=$2

  find $basedir -type f | egrep "(\.jar|\.war|\.ear)$" | while read jarFile; do

    jar tf $jarFile | grep $searchString > /tmp/findJar.tmp

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then

      echo " *** $jarFile"
      cat /tmp/findJar.tmp
    fi
  done

  rm /tmp/findJar.tmp 2> /dev/null
}
```

and then you can invoke it like this `findJar $my_jar_dir ActionMethod` and it should tell you which jars contain a Class called 'ActionMethod'.

Comment: ActionMethod is resolved.But,It shows package "net.sf.japi.swing" does not exist for ActionFactory methode.Please check it that one also.

Comment: yes, you need to add 'action' after 'net.sf.japi.swing': 'net.sf.japi.swing.action'.

Comment: You can use a standard zip-file extraction program, such as winzip, or 7-zip to inspect the contents of your jar-files.

Comment: Oh,yes I added that one.But,ActionFactory class is not available in that package.

Comment: Ha,I downloaded and extract it.But,the package doesn't have ActionFactory class.Please check it.It has ComponentFactory class.

Comment: Please check that ActionFactory class package also.

Comment: I think you have enough information to perform these checks yourself.

Comment: I have checked for that for yesterday onwards.I didn't find anything about ActionFactory class.Try it once.

Comment: Did you check other jar-files that 'japi' have available?

Comment: Yes,I had search for that.But,It shows the above specified jar file only.But,it doesn't contain ActionFactory class.

Comment: Sounds like their example code is out of date, you should raise a question with japi maintainers.